# How can I avoid pressing a button 2 times to change the boolean?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
package app.playstore.boulderspot.Login_SignUp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import app.playstore.boulderspot.Main.MainActivity;
import app.playstore.boulderspot.R;

public class Boulderspot_Log_In extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Login";
    public static boolean status;
    private Button btn_log_in;
    private TextView txt_sign_up;
    private TextView terms_conditions_txt;
    private ImageView img_google_log_in;
    private ImageView img_facebook_sign_in;
    private EditText editText_name_log_in;
    private EditText editText_pwd_log_in;

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Login");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.log_in_layout);

        init_views();
        button_click();


    }

    private void button_click() {
        btn_log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                check_input();

            }
        });
    }

    private void check_input() {
        if (editText_name_log_in.getText().toString().equals("")|| editText_pwd_log_in.getText().toString().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{
           if (check_data(editText_name_log_in.getText().toString(), editText_pwd_log_in.getText().toString())){
               Intent intent = new Intent(Boulderspot_Log_In.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);

           }
           else{
               Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

        }





    }

    private boolean check_data(final String User, final String pwd) {
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Data_of_post:" + postSnapshot.child("User").getValue());
                    if (postSnapshot.child("User").getValue().toString().equals(User)
                            && postSnapshot.child("Passwort").getValue().toString().equals( pwd)){

                        Log.d(TAG,"arrived?");
                        setstatus();



                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d(TAG,"Data_of_post_comparison:" + postSnapshot.child("User").getValue() + " " + User + "next" + postSnapshot.child("Passwort").getValue()+ " " + pwd);



                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG,"status_of_boolean" + status);
        return status;
    }

    private void setstatus() {
        status = true;
        Log.d(TAG,"hey"+status);
    }


    private void init_views() {
        btn_log_in = findViewById(R.id.btn_log_in);
        txt_sign_up = findViewById(R.id.sign_up_txt);
        terms_conditions_txt = findViewById(R.id.terms_conditions_txt);
        img_facebook_sign_in = findViewById(R.id.facebook_logo_log_in);
        img_google_log_in = findViewById(R.id.google_logo_log_in);
        editText_name_log_in = findViewById(R.id.edit_name_log_in);
        editText_pwd_log_in = findViewById(R.id.edit_log_in_pwd);


    }
}
```

At the moment when I start the Activity and I press the button once, nothin happens and my boolean is still set to false(but data is correct). When I press it a second time I am redirected to the next Activity. But why is my boolean value not changed at the first press? And how can I correct my code so that it works the first time?

Comment: I would guess that you need to add your `ValueEventListener` _before_ the first click instead of _on_ the first click. Just a guess.

Comment: But when the the user clicks I know that he entered his data in the edittext. How can I get and check the data before hand if there is no input?

Comment: @CalebSeeling See my updated answer with solution to your issue. Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `ValueEventListener` inside the `check_data()` which is not correct. Listeners are attached first and called later when the specific event happens. In this case the `ValueEventListener` will be trigger asynchronously once after it is set and once for future data changes.

So by the time your `check_data()` executes `return status` statement, the listener you attached hasn't been triggered so the value of `status` remains unchanged. And it triggers most definitely for the first time after your `check_data()` method ends. So by the time you click  again the value of `status` had been changed.

Another issue is that you are setting a new listener every time you click which is utter chaos. Also don't pass the field values directly to the listener.

Here is what you can do.

Set the listener in **`onCreate()`** and store `dataSnapshot` that you receive in different variable for later use like this **:**

```
private  DataSnapShot myDataSnapshot;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.log_in_layout);

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           myDataSnapshot = dataSnapshot;
        }
    });

    init_views();
    button_click();


}
```

Now in **`check_data()`** just retrieve username and password from the `myDataSnapshot` variable you stored earlier and compare it with the user entered values like this **:**

```
private boolean check_data(final String User, final String pwd) {

    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : myDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Data_of_post:" + postSnapshot.child("User").getValue());
        if (postSnapshot.child("User").getValue().toString().equals(User)
                && postSnapshot.child("Passwort").getValue().toString().equals( pwd)){
            Log.d(TAG,"arrived?");
            setstatus();
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG,"Data_of_post_comparison:" + postSnapshot.child("User").getValue() + " " + User + "next" + postSnapshot.child("Passwort").getValue()+ " " + pwd);
        }

    }

    Log.d(TAG,"status_of_boolean" + status);
    return status;
}
```

Hope this helps.

***SIDE NOTE:*** Since you need data only once when this login activity starts I would suggest that instead of attaching a listener you use [GetValueAsync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once) to read data only once. Just remember this is also an asynchronous call.